# In iCloud(+), can you allocate/limit portions of your shared storage to family members?

Tags: icloud, family-sharing

When using *Family Sharing* to share storage with *Family* members on your *iCloud*/*iCloud+* account, is it possible to limit the amount of storage each *Family* member may use?

If not, is it possibly to share *iCloud+* features with your *Family* without sharing your storage?

ref: [Share iCloud+ with your Family](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208147)